# How can I delete USE2-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2 on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-billing

I'm having trouble with my billing. I deleted all the instances, VPC's, I basically cleared the whole account. Yet, I'm getting billed for USE2-EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this? I don't have any EBS volumes in any of the AWS regions (I Checked them all)

This is the screenshot of my expenses:
[Expenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwBKq.png)

Comment: What about snapshots or AMIs?

Comment: Everything deleted, literally everything. @Marcin